# ¿Como integrar siris famework de Go con ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs, go

En un proyecto ya esta definido que vamos a usar Golang para el Backend y su framwork Siris, pero para el Frontend se va a usar react. No he visto antes esa integracion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estaba viendo que Siris utiliza los metodos HTTP, como GET, POST, UPDATE, DELETE, hay un cliente http muy fácil de usar y muy efectivo llamado Axios
https://github.com/axios/axios
la documentación es muy clara
veo que siris en main se encuentra este metodo

```
  // Method GET: http://localhost:8080/profile/anytypeofstring
    app.Get("/profile/{username:string}", profileByUsername)
```

en axios vas a usar algo así

```
axios.get('/profile?username=nombre')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

como utiliza promesas te devolverá una respuesta del servidor, o un error.
hace poco construí una aplicación con vuejs, axios y go funciona excelente. saludos